# Unity Countdown Script using Triggers for Start and Finish

Tags: unity-game-engine, timer, triggers, countdown

I am using the 3d Game Kit inside of Unity and trying to display a timer upon the player entering a trigger and then stopping the timer once they reach a ending trigger. The kit uses a dialogue canvas that I am unfamiliar with and trying to figure out.

---

**Update**

I've got the timer now on my UI and can make it stop when entering a trigger, but Im not sure how to make it start when a player enters a trigger. Right now it is just starting whenever the game starts.

```c#
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public Text timerText; 
    private float startTime; 
    private bool finished = false; 

    void Start () 
    { 
        float startTimer = Time.time; 
    } 

    void Update () 
    { 
        if (finished) return; 

        float t = Time.time - startTime; 
        string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString(); 
        string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2"); 
        timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds; 
    } 

    public void Finish() 
    { 
        finished = true; 
        timerText.color = Color.yellow; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? The countdown? The Triggers? Please show us what you have so far

Comment: I have the triggers in place and am having trouble with scripts and getting them to display on the kit's "Dialogue Canvas"

Comment: Did you have a look at this: https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/projects/3d-game-kit/using-counters-and-switches ? At the very bottom there is an example for setting text on the DialogueCanvas. I don't know the 3D game Kit in specific but I guess it is just using a `Canvas` and somewhere inside of it a `Text` component. You can change it's text if you reference it in a script and do `Text.text = "asd"`

Comment: The thing is I looked up that package and have no ambitions to download a (more than) 5GB example only to look into it ... if you can produce a minimal working project only including really necessary stuff I might be able to help you

Comment: Yeah, I get it. I'll see what i can do. I was trying to find someone who's been able to do something similar before. I'm focusing more on level design for my project, but I wanted to have some code in there for the countdown timer aspect. I'm not as experienced in that realm, but I wanted to learn.

Comment: So I've got a timer now on my UI and can make it stop when entering a trigger, but Im not sure how to make it start when a player enters a trigger. Right now it is just starting whenever the game starts.

Comment: ` public class Timer : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text timerText;
    private float startTime;
    private bool finished = false;  
    void Start () {
        float startTimer = Time.time;
    } 
 void Update () {
        if (finished)
            return;
  float t = Time.time - startTime;
        string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
        string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");
        timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
 }
    public void Finish()
    {
        finished = true;
        timerText.color = Color.yellow;
    }
}`

Comment: This is a complete different question and not the scope of the current one. Please open a new question for this. But before you do so, make sure this wasn't already asked before ( I'm pretty sure it was)

Comment: It is not a different a question, I've just advanced in the progress. I still cant make it start on a trigger. I've searched and could not find anything related to what I am trying to do.

Comment: please see the update I made on your question: Post any additional information you have as edit to the question not here in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: in your `Start` method you declare a new local variable `float startTimer` but never do something with it so the classes "global" variable `float startTime` will allways start with the value `0`.

Than your `Update` simply allways runs every frame so the countdown starts right ahead.

---

Reading `Countdown` I would understand that you want timer that reduces over time and does something when the value reaches `0` (otherwise I wouldn't call it countdown). There are various approaches to make a countdown. I think the closest to what you have already would probably be something like

```c#
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
    public Text timerText;

    // a callback (like onClick for Buttons) for doing stuff when Countdown finished
    public UnityEvent OnCountdownFinished;

    // here the countdown runs later
    private float timer; 

    // for starting, pausing and stopping the countdown
    private bool runTimer;

    // just a control flag to avoid continue without pausing before
    private bool isPaused;

    // start countdown with duration
    public void StartCountdown(float duration) 
    { 
        timer = duration; 
        runTimer = true;
    } 

    // stop and reset the countdown
    public void StopCountdown()
    {
        ResetCountdown();
    }

    // pause the countdown but remember current value
    public void PauseCountdown()
    {
        if(!runTimer)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Cannot pause if not runnning");
            return;
        }

        runTimer = false;
        isPaused = true;
    }

    // continue countdown after it was paused
    public void ContinueCountdown()
    {
        if(!isPaused)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Countdown was not paused! Cannot continue if not started");
            return;
        }

        runTimer = true;
        isPaused = false;
    }

    private void Update() 
    { 
        if (!runTimer) return;

        if (timer <= 0)
        {
            Finished();
        }

        // reduces the timer value by the time passed since last frame
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;

        string minutes = ((int)timer / 60).ToString(); 
        string seconds = (timer % 60).ToString("f2"); 

        // a bit more readable
        timerText.text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", minutes, seconds); 
    } 


    private void ResetCountdown()
    {
        timerText.text = "0:00";
        runTimer = false;
        isPaused = false;
        timer = 0;
    }

    // called when the countdown exceeds and wasn't stopped before
    private void Finished() 
    { 
        // do what ever should happen when the countdown is finished

        // simpliest way is to call the UnityEvent and set up the rest via inspector
        // (same way as with onClick on Buttons)
        OnCountdownFinished.Invoke();

        // and reset the countdown
        ResetCountdown();
    } 
}
```

you could also add more Callbacks for `OnCountdownStarted`, `OnCountdownPaused` etc.

Now you can call those methods with the Triggers

```c#
// somehow you have to get the reference to the component
// if the trigger callbacks are in the same class you don't need this ofcourse
Timer _timer;

// how long the countdown should take
float countdownDuration;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    _timer.StartCountdown(countdownDuration)
}


void OnTrigerExit(Collider col)
{
    _timer.StopCountdown();
}
```

if you rather require the pause and continue you could make the two flags `runTimer` and `isPaused` public and do

```c#
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if(!_timer.runTimer)
    {
        _timer.StartCountdown(countdownDuration)
    }
    else
    {
        _timer.ContinueCountdown();
    }
}


void OnTrigerExit(Collider col)
{
    if(!_timer.runTimer) return;

    _timer.PauseCountdown();
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I am wanting a timer to start counting up. I know I mentioned a countdown, but I really meant a timer that starts at 0 and goes until the player reaches a "finish line" that stops the timer.